# External Webcam doesn't work on Cheese but works on other apps

Tags: webcam, cheese

I am using an external webcam on a Surface Pro 5 and it works fine with Zoom and video via Chrome.  The internal webcam doesn't work.  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and am using the linux surface kernel.

When the external webcam is connected I open Cheese it says "There was error playing video from the webcam."  I go to preferences and choose the correct "USB PHY 2.0: USB Camera" for the camera and choose resolution 640x360 for photo and video (doesn't give other options).  I then close preferences the problem remains.  I close and restart Cheese and once again doesn't work, and try the same move in preferences with no different results.

Please let me know if you can help.  Thank you!

Comment: Try guvcview from the package of the same name.  It can work with some cameras that cheese doesn't.

Comment: That sort of works but image is green and i cant figure out how to take a photo.